# 12.04 displaying video via with vga with optimus disabled but external display not detected

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, display, resolution

I have a Dell vostro 3446 notebook with nvidia optimus. Since I do not need the capabilities of the dedicated gpu, I have blacklisted the nouveau driver and switched off the nvidia gpu with bbswitch(better battery backup).

The notebook has only a VGA output( no HDMI )

I connected the notebook to a samsung TV with a vga cable. The first time the cable was connected the TV screen was filled edge to edge with a resolution same as the native resolution of the notebook screen- 1366 X 768. Did a reboot and and now the same screen was displayed with a resolution of 1920X1080. So basically the vga output was displayed inside a 1366 X 768 window with black bands on the right and at the bottom.

I checked System Settings> Displays . The "Mirror" checkbox is disabled and only the laptop screen has been detected displayed as "Laptop". No second display detected.

I basically need the vga output to be displayed in 1920 X 1080 on the TV and ability to switch of the laptop screen.

Any help is much appreciated.

If you need me to run any tools to gather error/debug mssgs plz let me know. I have tried a few myself and here are the outputs:

### xrandr

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1366 x 768, current 1366 x 768, maximum 1366 x 768
default connected 1366x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
1366x768        0.0*
```

### xorg -configure

This displayed an error at the end:

```
Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices.
Configuration failed.  ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log Server terminated with error (2). 
Closing log file.
```

And here is the **xorg.conf** file:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath     "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/  TrueType"
    FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "extmod"
    Load  "dri"
    Load  "dri2"
    Load  "glx"
    Load  "dbe"
    Load  "record"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor1"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>:   "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "ShadowFB"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "Rotate"                # <str>
        #Option     "fbdev"                 # <str>
        #Option     "debug"                 # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "fbdev"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>:   "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "ShadowFB"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DefaultRefresh"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ModeSetClearScreen"    # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card1"
    Driver      "vesa"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen1"
    Device     "Card1"
    Monitor    "Monitor1"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1):

You may still need to install the "bumblebee" package to manage the Optimus GPU properly, even if you don't use the NVidia side of it.

I have a ThinkPad T410s with Optimus graphics that refuses to do anything properly despite having the BIOS configured to use the Intel GPU only, until I installed Bumblebee. Now it's happy.

Comment: Thanks @jeff-sereno. Installed bumblebee. But still did not detect the display. Should I remove nouveau blacklist and enable the card with bbswitch?